# Nodejs - node-twitter-api - session lost after redirecting from twitter authentication

Tags: node.js

I am using node-twitter-api module in node.js. Session getting lost after redirecting from twitter authentication page.

```
app.get('/p/twitterLogin', routes.twitterLogin);
app.get('/p/twitterAuthenticated', routes.twitterAuthenticated);


var twitterAPI = require('node-twitter-api');
var twitter = new twitterAPI({
    consumerKey: 'some_key',
    consumerSecret: 'some_key_secret',
    callback: 'some_callback_url'
});


exports.twitterLogin = function(req, res){
    console.log("Twitter Login");
    twitter.getRequestToken(function(error, requestToken, requestTokenSecret, results){
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error getting OAuth request token : " + error);
        }else {         
            req.session.twitterRequestToken = requestToken;
            req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret = requestTokenSecret;
            console.log("req.session.twitterRequestToken :::: " + req.session.twitterRequestToken);
            console.log("req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret" + req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret);   
            res.json(200, { "requestToken": requestToken,"requestTokenSecret" : requestTokenSecret,"results" : results});
        }
    });

};
```

Once twitter authentication is completed , again i am trying to get the request token from session. Here req.session.twitterRequestToken  is undefined.

```
exports.twitterAuthenticated = function(req, res){
    console.log("req.session.twitterRequestToken :::: "+req.session.twitterRequestToken);
    console.log("req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret"+req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret);
    twitter.getAccessToken(req.session.twitterRequestToken, req.session.twitterRequestTokenSecret, req.query.oauth_verifier, function(error, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
                twitter.verifyCredentials(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, function(error, data, response) {
                if (error) {
                } else {
                    console.log(data["screen_name"]);
                }
            });
        }
    });

};
```

Thanks.